# react-hook-form: Mapping onChange to a different property

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a radixUI component that takes in an `onPressedChange` prop. How can I map this to `onChange` in react-hook-form?

`onChange` from `react-hook-form` doesn't accept a custom function that satisfies the typing when I try as per below.

```js
import * as Toggle from "@radix-ui/react-toggle";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { register, watch, getValues } = useForm();

  return (
    <div>
      <Toggle.Root {...register("basic")} />

      <code>watchAll: {JSON.stringify(watch(), null, 2)}</code>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried spreading it out like below but my functions don't satisfy the `onChange` typings...

```js
import * as Toggle from "@radix-ui/react-toggle";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { register, watch, getValues } = useForm();
  const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register('basic'); 
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Toggle.Root onPressedChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} name={name} ref={ref} />
                                 // ^This doesn't work.
                                 // Neither does `onPressedChange={pressed=>onChange(pressed)}`

      <code>watchAll: {JSON.stringify(watch(), null, 2)}</code>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `onChange` prop from `react-hook-form` accepts the following ChangeHandler:

```js
type ChangeHandler = (event: {
    target: any;
    type?: any;
}) => Promise<void | boolean>;
```

and the typing for `onPressedChange` is:

```js
type OnPressedChangeHandler = (pressed: boolean) => void
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to map it is to simply use the `setValue` method from `useForm()` instead of `onChange`.

You could use something like this since you know the name of the element, "basic".

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { register, watch, setValue } = useForm();
  const { onBlur, name, ref } = register("basic");

  const onPressedChange = (boolean) => {
    setValue("basic", boolean);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Toggle.Root
        onPressedChange={onPressedChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        name={name}
        ref={ref}
      />
      <code>watchAll: {JSON.stringify(watch(), null, 2)}</code>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here's an [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quizzical-spence-ll8mqm).